# Getting " org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 'can't convert from BSON type string to Date' " exception

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Below spring data mongo DB aggregation query meant to get available teachers based on who doesn't have 20 hr / 15 hr workload for a week.

```
public List<Calendar> findAvailableTeachersV2(List<java.util.Date> leanerPlannedSlotList, int hoursPerWeek) {

        log.info("TeachersAvailabilityQuery.getTeachers()");
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(

                match(where("schedule.startDate").in(leanerPlannedSlotList)
                        .andOperator(where("schedule.status").is("AVAILABLE"))),

                Aggregation.unwind("$schedule"),

                project("_id", "timeZone", "schedule").and("schedule.startDate").as("startDate")
                        .and(DateOperators.IsoWeek.isoWeek("schedule.startDate")).as("week").and("schedule.status")
                        .as("status").and(LiteralOperators.Literal.asLiteral(0.5)).as("duration"),

                // TODO
                group("_id", "week", "status")
                        .addToSet(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("status").is("AVAILABLE"))
                                .thenValueOf("startDate").otherwise(""))
                        .as("startDate").push("duration").as("duration").count().as("bookedDuration"),

                // TODO
                // Need to check intersection
                project("_id").and(SetOperators.SetIntersection.arrayAsSet("startDate").intersects("startDate"))
                        .as("availableSlots")
                        .and(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("schedule.status").is("BOOKED"))
                                .thenValueOf("bookedDuration").otherwise(0))
                        .as("bookedDuration"),

                Aggregation.unwind("availableSlots", true),

                // TODO
                // Need to check the sum of bookedDuration
                group("_id").addToSet("availableSlots").as("availableSlots").sum("bookedDuration")
                        .as("bookedDuration"),

                // TODO
                // Need to check size condition for: availableSlots
                match(where("bookedDuration").gt(hoursPerWeek).andOperator(where("availableSlots").size(0).gt(0))),

                Aggregation.unwind("availableSlots"), group("_id").addToSet("availableSlots").as("availableSlots"));

        AggregationResults<Calendar> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION_NAME, Calendar.class);
        List<Calendar> calendarList = results.getMappedResults();

        return calendarList;
    }
```

**Please refer the below Exception stack trace:**

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException:Command failed with error 16006: 'can't convert from BSON type string to Date' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-uwrbw.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1553603169, "i" : 5 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date", "code" : 16006, "codeName" : "Location16006", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1553603169, "i" : 5 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "gkjiKThKxdvt+K/4stNTlMjM9rE=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6616309008233922561" } } } }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 16006: 'can't convert from BSON type string to Date' on server cluster0-shard-00-00-uwrbw.mongodb.net:27017. The full response is { "operationTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1553603169, "i" : 5 } }, "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date", "code" : 16006, "codeName" : "Location16006", "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1553603169, "i" : 5 } }, "signature" : { "hash" : { "$binary" : "gkjiKThKxdvt+K/4stNTlMjM9rE=", "$type" : "00" }, "keyId" : { "$numberLong" : "6616309008233922561" } } } }
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:131)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2589)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeCommand(MongoTemplate.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$BatchAggregationLoader.aggregateBatched(MongoTemplate.java:3137)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$BatchAggregationLoader.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:3113)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1937)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1841)
```